# C++ closure behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, closures

I wanted to make sure I understood how closures in c++ worked "behind the scenes", so I wrote a program (Visual Studio 2019) to see the behavior in detail:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    list<int> ints = { 1, 2 };
    void display(string msg) const {
        cout << setw(8) << msg << ": this = 0x" << this << ", ints.front() = " << ints.front() << endl;
    }
public:
    A() { ints.front() += 1; display("A()"); }
    A(const A& other) : ints(other.ints) { ints.front() += 1; display("A(A&)"); }
    A(const A&& other) noexcept : ints(other.ints) { ints.front() += 1; display("A(A&&)"); }
    ~A() { display("~A()"); }
    void doSomething() const { display("A doing something"); }
};


function<void (void)> fn()
{
    A a;

    auto rfn = [=]() { 
        cout << "In Lambda: &a = 0x" << &a << endl;
        a.doSomething(); 
    };

    return rfn;
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto fn2 = fn();
        fn2();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran this I got the following output:

```
     A(): this = 0x010FF948, ints.front() = 2
   A(A&): this = 0x010FF934, ints.front() = 3
  A(A&&): this = 0x010FF838, ints.front() = 4
  A(A&&): this = 0x010FFA4C, ints.front() = 5
    ~A(): this = 0x010FF838, ints.front() = 4
    ~A(): this = 0x010FF934, ints.front() = 3
    ~A(): this = 0x010FF948, ints.front() = 2
In Lambda: &a = 0x010FFA4C
A doing something: this = 0x010FFA4C, ints.front() = 5
    ~A(): this = 0x010FFA4C, ints.front() = 5
```

I can understand the first copy constructor, but the two rvalue-reference constructor calls have me baffled.  Why are they needed?

Comment: `rfn` is converted to `std::function<void()>` which moves the closure, and its captured objects. Then, returning an object copies it in this case. If you `auto rfn` to `std::function<void()> rfn;` one of the move constructions can go away since the return value optimization can apply. And if you change `fn()`'s return type to `auto` the move constructors should disappear. This behavior isn't about closures, this is just about how return values propagate.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisAndrieux.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I still get the same number and types of constructors, but now in a slightly different order.

Comment: The result depends on the compiler and build flags. Since you are on Visual Studio try the "Release" configuration. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/hboEbYefx) you can see all the move constructions are removed on GCC when `std::function` is replaced with `auto`. Again, this is not related to closures.  You can read about Return Value Optimization and Named Return Value Optimization.

Comment: Ah.  You are right.  Using Release I see one less RValue constructor (and associated destructor) called.  Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed that if I don't create an intermediate variable (`rfn`) in `fn` to hold the `function` object and just return the lambda directly then, even in Debug mode, I eliminate on of the move constructors.

Comment: I think since C++17, effectively return value optimization is mandatory in that case. You return a prvalue expression with the same type as the function's return type.

Comment: Thanks, @FrançoisAndrieux.  I was just reading about NRVO and that was what prompted me to make this test.